# Escape double quotes within double quotes with Regex[JS]

Tags: javascript, regex, json, escaping

I have a JSON string: `'{"place": {"address": "Main Street, \"The House\""}}'`.
Before parsing it with `JSON.parse()` I have to make sure that the double quotes within double quotes are escaped properly.
I was trying to come up with the regex that would match "The House", but failed to so.
**Any idea on how can I achieve desired result?**

Comment: Do you want a RegEx to match quotes? Or do you want to see if a JSON string is properly escaped

Comment: That's not a JSON string (because the quotes *aren't* escaped properly). Can't you change the code that creates the string to escape things properly in the first place?

Comment: @vihan1086 I want to match the double quotes within double quotes only.

Comment: @AnatoliyGatt Try this RegEx: `"((?:(?=(?:\\)*)\\.|.)*?)"` https://regex101.com/r/tC8bZ5/2, and https://regex101.com/r/tC8bZ5/5

Comment: @nnnnnn Edited. But when you espace it as i did, and using as an input to JSON.parse(), the escaping disappears, therefore I need to use '\\"' instead of '\"'.

Comment: Your edited string is now valid JSON *unless it is a string literal* in your JS code, in which case you'd need to escape the backslashes too so that the resulting string is valid JSON. But I don't understand why you need to test anything before parsing it. Again, can't you ensure when creating it that it is properly escaped? Where does the string come from?

Comment: `"[^"]*\\"[^"]*\\""`

Comment: @nnnnnn because if the quotes within quotes are not escaped properly, parser throws exception and fail the whole process.

Comment: Yes, so, again, have the code that creates the string do the escaping properly in the first place. Where does the string come from? Or catch the parse exception and take appropriate action then.

Comment: For the above string as is, `var re = /\\"([^\\"]+)/g; `

Comment: And [here](https://regex101.com/r/yS3lY3/3) where you can fiddle with it

Comment: Perhaps `"address"\s*:\s*"((?:(?=(?:\\)*)\\.|.)*?)"` might work also

Comment: @nnnnnn I can't ensure correctness, because it comes from server.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This would be possible with the help of positive lookahead assertion.

```js
var s = '{"place": {"address": "Main Street, "The House""}}';
alert(s.replace(/"((?:"[^"]*"|[^"])*?)"(?=[:}])/g, function(m,group)
                          {
                            return '"' + group.replace(/"/g, '\\"') + '"'
                          }))
```

OR

```js
var s = '{"place": {"address": "Main Street, "The House"", "country": "United Kingdom"}}';
alert(s.replace(/"((?:"[^"]*"|[^"])*?)"(?=[:},])(?=(?:"[^"]*"|[^"])*$)/gm, function(m,group)
                          {
                            return '"' + group.replace(/"/g, '\\"') + '"'
                          }))
```

Comment: How should I modify it, to work properly with something like this: '{"place": {"address": "Main Street, "The House"", "country": "United Kingdom"}}'?

Comment: you may use this regex `"((?:"[^"]*"|[^"])*?)"(?=[:},])(?=(?:"[^"]*"|[^"])*$)`, https://regex101.com/r/zN9sQ2/6

Comment: Thank you! You saved me a lot of time!

Comment: it doesnt work in case there is only 1 double quote present in data. {"data": "12" is the length of a foot"}

Comment: C# version of it worked for me. Thanks!
using System;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string s = "{\"place\": {\"address\": \"Main Street, \\\"The House\\\"\", \"country\": \"United Kingdom\"}}";
        Console.WriteLine(Regex.Replace(s, "\"((?:\"[^\"]*\"|[^\"])*?)\"(?=[:},])(?=(?:\"[^\"]*\"|[^\"])*$)", delegate (Match m)
        {
            string group = m.Groups[1].Value;
            return "\"" + group.Replace("\"", "\\\"") + "\"";
        }));
    }
}